# Magento 2 update Special Price Programatically with using custom script

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

I want to update special price for each associated product of configurable product.I have migrated data from Magento 1 to Magento 2,since Magento special price was managed by main configurable but in Magento 2, special price are managed by each associated product hence we require to update special price for each associated product by picking special price of configurable.

I want to do it by writing a custom script root of Magento.

Please suggest me how we can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mangeto2 default product import feature rather then to create custom script.

Product Import csv columns :-

```
sku,special_price,special_price_from_date,special_price_to_date
```